# Display photo in GeoExt popup

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, wms, features, geoext

I have point feature with name PointPhoto.
This feature have attribute:

- id
- area
- PhotoPath

Now I am using GeoExt popup to display this attributes, but I can't find a way to display image from image path, this is the code:

```
 <html> 
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script> 
        <script src="../OpenLayers-2.9.1/OpenLayers.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="geoext/script/GeoExt.js"></script> 
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8181/geoserver/openlayers/theme/default/style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../proj4js/lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="geoext/resources/css/popup.css"> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
var app, items = [], controls = []; 
var store;
Ext.onReady(function() { 
            app = new Ext.Viewport({ 
                layout: "border",
                  items: items 
            }); 
        }); 
        items.push({ 
            xtype: "gx_mappanel", 
            ref: "mapPanel", 
            region: "center", 
            map: { 
                numZoomLevels: 19, 
                controls: controls 
            }, 
            extent: OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray([ 
                    2189574.7042680467, 5418655.108865695,
                    2199298.319819289, 5426457.253025988
                    ]), 
            layers: [new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
                "cite:PointPhoto", 
                "http://192.168.1.2:8181/geoserver/cite/wms", 
                {layers: "cite:PointPhoto"}, 
                {isBaseLayer: false} 
            )] ,
            }); 
            controls.push(
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({position: new OpenLayers.Pixel(2, 15)}),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()
           );


controls.push(new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({ 
autoActivate: true, 
infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml", 
maxFeatures: 3, 
eventListeners: { 
        "getfeatureinfo": function(e) { 
            var items = []; 
            Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) { 
                items.push({ 
                    xtype: "propertygrid", 
                    title: feature.fid, 
                    source: feature.attributes 
                         }); 
            }); 

            new GeoExt.Popup({ 
                title: "Feature Info", 
                width: 200, 
                height: 200, 
                layout: "accordion", 
                map: app.mapPanel, 
                location: e.xy, 
                items: items[0] 
            }).show(); 
        } 
    } 
})); 


     </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

[image]

My question is how I can display image inside of this popup?

Answer (score 1):

Since the feature pop up is HTML code ... try wrapping the img path with :

```
<img src=..... />
```

This is how I did it on my ExtJS Grid.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is parcially correct. You have to use a html tag. the easy way to do it, since the content of the featur info window is fetched by geoserver is using a getfeatureInfo template; in the content.ftl you should put someting like :

```
<ul>
<#list features as feature>
  <li><b>Point of interest, "${feature.NAME.value}"</b>: <br/>
  <img src="http://host/folder${feature.PhotoPath.value}"/>
  </li>
</#list>
</ul>
```

for more information have a look at:

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html